# Is there a way to pipe the `hdiutil create` into a raw stream without needing to store it first?

Tags: terminal, mac, dmg

I would like to do something like

```
hdiutil create dest_file.dmg -srcdevice /dev/disk3 | curl -TX - PUT \
    -H "Authorization: Token" \
    --output /dev/null \
    "https://uploadlink.com"
```

so that I do not need to store `dest_file.dmg` first in order to upload (as I don't have enough diskspace for this). Is there an option to stream the file and upload using `hdiutil create`?

Comment: Why can't you just run `hdiutil create foo.dmg ...; cat foo.dmg | curl ...` in one line?

Comment: The issue I'm having is that the resulting `foo.dmg` file is larger than any storage device I have, and so I'm hoping to directly pipe it in a stream, without taking substantial space first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't immediately seem possible, no.

The hdiutil tool itself has no option to write to stdout.

It cannot be tricked by using `/dev/fd/1` as the output file either.

Creating a named pipe using the `mkfifo` command doesn't work, as the hdiutil checks for the existence of the file before starting.

In this case it is possible easier for you to simply stream over the raw disk contents, and then convert it to a dmg on the receiving end (depending on which utilities you have available there). In your case it is a simple dmg file, so converting it is just a matter of adding a small footer structure to the end of the file after transferring it.

You could transfer the raw data using a command like:

```
dd if=/dev/rdisk3 bs=1m | curl -TX - PUT -H "Authorization: Token" --output /dev/null "https://uploadlink.com"
```

Comment: thank you for the `dd` option! If I were to upload according to the command above, what is the default format of the file? Would it be something like an `.img`?

Comment: There’s no “format” - it’s just the raw data. You could call that an “.img”, yes. A simple dmg is also just raw data with a footer appended to it. Why do you want a dmg at all?

Comment: The overaching motivating is to create a backup/archive of my macOS time machine backups.db folder. It is currently 4 TB out of 6 TB total on an external hard drive, and so I cannot first create a dmg, then upload. I wanted to use the dmg to preserve hard links, as I found out just creating a `tar` archive file destroys some things in the backups. I'd like to stream it so that I can upload it without having to buy a new drive. Is this an approach you would take?

Comment: If you want to take that route, remember that the file system storing the time machine backups must not be mounted when you back it up. Using dd will transfer the raw data, just like hdiutil copies the raw data. In both cases hard links will be preserved. I would just use dd.

Comment: wow thank you, I had no idea about the mounting. why exactly does the mountain incur issues? thanks!

Comment: If you take a raw copy of a mounted file system, you risk loosing data. When you write to a file on file system - data doesn't go on the disk immediately. It will be cached in RAM for a time, and several writes might not go on disk in the order that they came in. When you take a raw copy of a file system, the data not written is obviously not included.